# equivalent of a JAR file for webassembly?

Tags: web-applications, deployment

Are there any published standards of archive files to hold webassembly (multiple files) with a metadata file that defines the entry point? I'm thinking of something similar to JAR or APK.

Answer (score -1):

A .WAR file seems to be exactly what you're looking for: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_(file_format)

Regarding metadata about entry points, "The /WEB-INF directory in the WAR file contains a file named web.xml which defines the structure of the web application."

Comment: A WAR file holds java code for deployment to a server. The OP is looking for something to hold webassembly code, presumably to serve to browsers.